# Database / Application Design - When to Denormalise?

Tags: database, normalization

I am working on an application which needs to store financial transactions for an account.

This data will then need to be queried in a number of ways. I'll need to list individual transactions, monthly totals by category, for example. I'll also need to show a monthly summary with opening / closing balances.

As I see it, I could approach this in the following ways:

1. From the point of view of database consistency and normalisation, this could be modelled as a simple list of transactions. Balances may then be calculated in the application by adding up every transaction from the beginning of time to the date of the balance you wish to display.
2. A slight variation on this would be to model the data in the same way, but calculate the balances in a stored procedure on the database server. Appreciate that this isn't hugely different to #1 - both of these issues will perform slower as more data gets added to the system.
3. End of month balances could be calculated and stored in a separate table (possibly updated by triggers). I don't really like this approach from a data consistency point of view, but it should scale better.

I can't really decide which way to go with this. Should I start with the 'purest' data model and only worry about performance when it becomes an issue? Should I assume performance will become a problem and plan for it from day one? Is there another option which I haven't thought of which would solve the issue better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at it like this, the calculations are going to take longer and longer and that majority of the monthly numbers before the previous 2-3 months will not be changing. This is a performance problem that has a 100% chance of happening as financial date will grow every month. Therefore looking at a solution in the design phase is NOT premature optimization, it is smart design.

I personally am in favor of only calculating such totals when they need to be calculated rather than every time they are queried. Yes the totals should be updated based on triggers on the table which will add a slight overhead to inserts and deletes. They will make the queries for selects much faster. In my experience users tend to be more tolerant of a slightly longer action query than a much longer select query. Overall this is a better design for this kind of data than a purely normalized model as long as you do the triggers correctly. In the long run, only calculating numbers that have changed will take up far less server resources.

This model will maintain data integrity as long as all transactions go through the trigger. The biggest culprit in that is usually data imports which often bypass triggers. If you do those kinds of imports make sure they have code that mimics the trigger code. Also make sure the triggers are for insert/update and delete and that they are tested using multiple record transactions not just against single records.

The other model is to create a data warehouse that populates on a schedule such as nightly. This is fine if the data can be just slightly out of date.  If the majority of queries of this consolidated data will be for reporting and will not involve the current month/day so much then this will work well and you can do it in an SSIS package.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete answer - really appreciate it! Must admit that I was leaning in this direction, but it's great to get a second opinion.